# How can i solve React useEffect clean up error issue

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

useEffect to call master table data of list eg. country, location.
I am using empty dependency list so that it will only load once it is mounted.
But the error is showing that clean up is not done properly so that it is leaking in memory.

This is the error i see in the console.

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in CorporateBasicProfileSection (at CorporateProfilePage.js:148)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Grid))
    in ForwardRef(Grid) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)) (at GridItem.js:25)
    in GridItem (at CorporateProfilePage.js:139)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Grid))
    in ForwardRef(Grid) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)) (at GridContainer.js:23)
    in GridContainer (at CorporateProfilePage.js:138)
```

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in CorporateManagerDetailSection (at CorporateProfilePage.js:152)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Grid))
    in ForwardRef(Grid) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)) (at GridItem.js:25)
    in GridItem (at CorporateProfilePage.js:150)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Grid))
    in ForwardRef(Grid) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)) (at GridContainer.js:23)
    in GridContainer (at CorporateProfilePage.js:138)
```

this is the clean up function in useEffect

CorporateBasicProfileSection

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    console.log("mountedbasic profile");
    if (mounted) {
      fetchIndustryList();
      fetchCompanyList();
    }
    return () => {
      console.log("unmounted basic profile");
      mounted = false;
    };
  }, []);
```

CorporateManagerDetailSection

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    if (mounted) {
      fetchCountryList();
      fetchAreaList();
      fetchLocationList();
    }
    return () => {
      mounted = false;
    };
  }, []);
```

and this is the corporate profile page where I call the sections to be visible when axios call is properly done

CorporateProfilePage.js

```
 {isUpdated ? (
        <div className={classNames(classes.main, classes.mainRaised)}>
          <div className={classes.container}>
            {isLoading ? (
              <LoadingModal />
            ) : (
 ////////SKIPPING ////////
<GridContainer>
                  <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={8}>
                    <Card>
                      <CardBody>
                        <h3 className={classes.cardTitle}>About</h3>
                        <h5 className={classes.cardDetail}>
                          {profileRecord.companyProfile}
                        </h5>
                      </CardBody>
                    </Card>
                    <CorporateBasicProfileSection />
                  </GridItem>
                  <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={4}>
                    <CorporateTagSection />
                    <CorporateManagerDetailSection />
                    <CorporateJobLinkSection />
                  </GridItem>
                </GridContainer>
```

I am not sure what is wrong in this code, This is not a modal component so I am not sure why it is erroring the above issue, please give me some guide. Thanks early.

Axios fetching code for getting master table data

```
export const getCountryId = () => {
  const res = axios.get(`${instanceUrl}/api/md/get-all-country`);
  return res;
};
export const getAreaCodeId = () => {
  const res = axios.get(`${instanceUrl}/api/md/get-all-area-code`);
  return res;
};
export const getLocationId = () => {
  const res = axios.get(`${instanceUrl}/api/md/get-all-location`);
  return res;
};
export const getEducationLevelId = () => {
  const res = axios.get(`${instanceUrl}/api/md/get-all-education-level`);
  return res;
};
export const getIndustryId = () => {
  const res = axios.get(`${instanceUrl}/api/md/get-all-industry`);
  return res;
};
export const getLocationById = (countryId) => {};
export const getSchoolId = () => {
  const res = axios.get(`${instanceUrl}/api/md/get-all-school`);
  return res;
};

export const getFieldStudyId = () => {
  const res = axios.get(`${instanceUrl}/api/md/get-all-study-field`);
  return res;
};

export const getCurrencyId = () => {
  const res = axios.get(`${instanceUrl}/api/md/get-all-currency`);
  return res;
};
export const getCompanyTypeId = () => {
  const res = axios.get(`${instanceUrl}/api/md/get-all-company-type`);
  return res;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing what the code for your axios fetches are I can't be sure, but if you're just doing fetches inside without any cancellation logic, those are still going to be ongoing if:

- the effect fires before the component is unmounted
- the fetches do not complete until after the component is unmounted.

There's details for how to cancel axios fetches here: https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation

You'll need to write logic for cancelling those fetches in your cleanup callback.

EDIT: You basically need to create a cancellation token in the effect (before calling the fetches), then pass that cancellation token to all of the fetches (as the documentation linked above notes, one cancellation token is sufficient for many requests)

So something like:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
    const source = CancelToken.source();
    fetchIndustryList(source.token);
    fetchCompanyList(source.token);
    return () => {
      source.cancel('Operation canceled by the user.');
      mounted = false;
    };
  }, []);
```

and you need to change all of your functions to accept that cancellation token:

```
export const getCountryId = (token) => {
  const res = axios.get(`${instanceUrl}/api/md/get-all-country`, { cancelToken: token });
  return res;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i will add my axios fetching at above,

Comment: @Jin I've updated the answer in respect of this. Is the example understandable?

Comment: Louis Chan you are a genius!!!!!!!! i have tried similar way of what you have shared with me and it is working great!!! Thanks so much! Have a wonderful day ahead :)))